# New app submission without retina images

Tags: iphone, app-store, retina-display, submission

I have one query related to news by Apple about app submission below. Does it mean that for the next app updates

1. I have to include both retina and non retina images for every image in my app?
2. OR Can I can selectively add the retina images and keep rest of the images non retina?
3. As having retina and non retina images both bundled in app will increase the app size, and there is limit on the size of app being submitted (50 MB), what should I do if the size increases beyond limit?

Link :- https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=3212013b

It says -

Starting May 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built for iOS devices with Retina display and iPhone apps must also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. Learn about preparing your apps by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

Thanks.

Comment: i bet they are just talking about system images of your app, as icons and default images (splashScreen images shown at startup of apps)

Comment: Moreover who said that size of app should be less than 50 MB. There are many games who's sizes are above 250 MB

Comment: App review guidelines clearly states the size limit as 50 MB

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html
Apps larger than 50MB in size will not download over cellular networks (this is automatically prohibited by the App Store)

Comment: @Pappu this limit only says those apps cannot be downloaded over 3G, its not an actual limit on the size of apps it just means apps beyond this size have to be downloaded over wifi. I believe the actual limit is about 2GB, but dont have a source for this (I once had an app rejected for being over size)

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough one but you should always try to keep your app within the Apple guidelines to get your app approved.

1. You should have both image.png, image@2x.png and image-568h@2x.png(when needed) for all apps. You could get away with just having an @2x.png image, and use it at 50%. Although that will blur the image when viewed on a 3G, 3GS etc.
   What you could do is to compress your images better. For .jpg there are some great compression tools out there. And for .png you could use something like [tinypng](http://tinypng.org), they do a great job with compressing images and keeping the quality. I have used that on several apps.
2. Same as above, you should try to keep good HIG practices, if you want happy customers and be sure to not get rejected when submitting the app. If you use non retina images they will be scaled up and really won't look good on either a 4, 4S or 5.
3. And as others have stated before me. Apple does approve apps that exceed 50mb, they just won't be downloaded via 3G.

   Quoted from the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

> **2.15** Apps larger than 50MB in size will not download over
>   cellular networks (this is    automatically prohibited by the App
>   Store)

Comment: I am thinking of adding retina images for only those which see distorted or stretched on iPhone 5 screen.Where can I get the confirmation regarding app approval process that I can selectively replace the images for retina support?

Is there any way to query to the apple group itself who actually do the app review for iPhone 5?

Currently I am testing my app on iPhone 5 and if some image seems scaled to me i am adding 2x image for it.

But again its subjective and I wanted to have approval of app reviewing authority for this approach.

Comment: The HIG says that you should supply a normal as well as an @2x. So in doing it the way you are planning to do it, you are in a way counting on that it will slide by. I'm on my phone ATM but when I'm on my Mac I can try to find the passage that states that you can use 2x only if you want?